# Setting default date on jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am working on a project with 2 datepicker inputs.  When the user selects a date from the first datepicker input I am trying to get the second datepicker input to show the month of the first datepicker input when the datepicker pops up.

For example a user select a date in input 1, lets say 3/13/2014.  When the user clicks on input 2 the datepicker by default goes to the current month.  I would like it so when the user clicks on input 2 the datepicker shows the month that was selected in input 1.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

[my JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/austin350s10/L10mrqnb/)

So far I have tried this:

```
//this does noting that I can tell
var defaultDate = $( "#date1" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate" );
$( "#date2" ).datepicker( "option", defaultDate );

//this actually takes the value of input 1 and inserts it into input 2
var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', $('#date1').val());  
$("#date2").datepicker( "setDate" , date1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the value of an [option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option), you need three parameters:

```
.datepicker("option", "[name of option]", newValue);
```

You can change the [defaultDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) option of the second datepicker to the value of the first textbox:

```
$("#date2").datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", $('#date1').val() );
```

This works since the default [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) is mm/dd/yyyy by default.

A working demo is here: <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L10mrqnb/4/)</kbd>

However, the demo has a visual flaw; you can see the first datepicker flash to its default date once you select a date. In order to fix this visual flaw, you can also set the defaultDate of the first datepicker to its new value:

```
$("#date2").datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", $('#date1').val() );
$("#date1").datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", $('#date1').val() );
```

An updated Demo is here: <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L10mrqnb/3/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I would use the events given by the actual date picker object. Then, onSelect just change the defaultDate.

I had to remove the datepicker auto-initialization (`role=date`) from the html for some reason though.

```
$(function(){
    $('#date1').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(date) {
            $('#date2').datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', date);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evilbuck/L10mrqnb/9/

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, I had to remove the `data-role="date"` HTML attribute in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/austin350s10/L10mrqnb/) for this to work.

Then you can utilize the [`$.datepicker.onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) to trigger a date change in your second datepicker whenever the first changes.

```
$("#date2").datepicker();
$("#date1").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(date){
    $("#date2").datepicker('setDate', date);
  }  
});
```

Refer live demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/LquLpkxc/).

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the **'defaultDate'** option in the **datepicker** function itself as shown below.

**defaultDate** supports multiple type

**Date:** A date object containing the default date.

**Number:** A number of days from today. For example 2 represents two days from today and -1 represents yesterday.

**String:** A string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, and "d" for days. For example, "+1m +7d" represents one month and seven days from today.

**See Working code is JsFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/yg51nzj8/3/

```
$("#date1").datepicker();

  $("#date2").datepicker({

  defaultDate: "-20y"

});

var dateObject = new Date(2011, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0); //Please note that month starts from zero! (year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds)

  $("#date3").datepicker({

  defaultDate: dateObject

});
```